# Reshaping data with unique values as columns

Tags: r, group-by, reshape, transpose

Generating dummy data

```
MainID=c('A1','A1','B2','C1','C1','C1','D2','D2')
HouseholdID=c('Ab1','Ab1','cb2','Ca2','cb2','cb3','Da1','db2')
relation=c('Spouse','Spouse','Child','Spouse','Child','Mother','Brother','Spouse')

df=data.table(MainID,HouseholdID,relation)
head(df)

   MainID HouseholdID relation
1:     A1         Ab1   Spouse
2:     A1         Ab1   Spouse
3:     B2         cb2    Child
4:     C1         Ca2   Spouse
5:     C1         cb2    Child
6:     C1         cb3   Mother
```

I need to reshape this data as below :

Desired outcome

```
MainID      Household1      Relation1       Household2         Relation2           Household3      Relation3
A1               Ab1           Spouse          NA                  NA                  NA              NA
B2               cb2           Child           NA                  NA                  NA              NA
C1               Ca2           Spouse          cb2                 Child               cb3            Mother
D2               Da1           Brother         db2                 Spouse              NA              NA
```

What is the best way to do this using `dplyr , reshape , tidyverse`  or any other methods/packages ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using "data.table", you can just take the unique values, then add a row indicator variable, and finally `dcast` to a wide format:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(unique(df)[, ind := rowid(MainID)], 
      MainID ~ ind, value.var = c("HouseholdID", "relation"))
#    MainID HouseholdID_1 HouseholdID_2 HouseholdID_3 relation_1 relation_2 relation_3
# 1:     A1           Ab1            NA            NA     Spouse         NA         NA
# 2:     B2           cb2            NA            NA      Child         NA         NA
# 3:     C1           Ca2           cb2           cb3     Spouse      Child     Mother
# 4:     D2           Da1           db2            NA    Brother     Spouse         NA
```